# What is the best way to do a password reset on backend for the frontend?

Tags: email, frontend, backend, reset-password

I am doing password reset and my understanding of the frontend is not very strong. What is the best way to handle the email link to reset your password? At the moment I have done this so the backend accepts email and redirect link. Sends a link in an email. Front will prepare a html, point it to the redirect link and receive redirect_link/?Token_valid=True&message=CredentialsValid&uidb64=Mg&token=5o5-0d1ffb5e5092d4e5c84d
And after the frontend will be able to make another request and transfer uidb64, token, and a new password. Did I do it right?